# Use Django's call command to start celery worker with celerybeat

Tags: django, celery

I'd like to start a Django celery worker from a Python script, with celerybeat. On the command line, I would do:

```
python manage.py celery worker --beat --schedule celerybeat-schedule.db
```

I tried this from a script, but it threw an exception:

```
from django.core.management import call_command
call_command("cerlery", "worker", "--beat", "--schedule", "celerybeat-schedule.db")
```

Comment: According to https://github.com/celery/django-celery/issues/247 it is not possible to start it using call_command

Answer (score 1):

I worked around it by doing this:

```
from djcelery.management.commands import celery
args = ['manage.py', 'celery', 'worker', '--beat', '--schedule',
        'celerybeat-schedule']
command = celery.Command()
command.run_from_argv(args)
```

But if it's possible to use `call_command`, I'd like to know how.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to do this..

```
./manage.py celeryd --event --beat --loglevel=INFO --logfile=./celeryd.log
```

Then to run the camera..

```
./manage.py celeryev --camera=djcelery.snapshot.Camera --logfile=./celeryev.log
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That works from the command line, but in my use case I need to invoke it from a script rather from than the shell.